# Prisma Mongodb: Optional 1:1 relation not working

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

I am trying to achieve a 1:1 **optional** relation with **Prisma** and **MongoDB**. I use the following Prisma schema:

```js
model User {
  id             String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email          String?        @unique
  profile        Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id             String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name           String?
  userId         String?        @unique @db.ObjectId
  user           User?          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

However, when a profile gets created and **userId** is null type, it will create a duplicate constraint error:

> Invalid `prisma.profile.create()` invocation: Unique constraint failed on the constraint

Based on my knowlegde and research, the only thing I came up with is by switching to a **many-to-many** relation however, this sound counterproductive to me.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What does your `prisma.profile.create()` call look like? It could be the case that the `userId` is being set to null when really you want `userId` to not be present.

Comment: @LoganAnderson I've tried that but that is not the case. I've found a workaround by removing the relation and simply just calling it 'userId'.